# How can I connect to an Http server with Basic Auth over SSL on Android?

Tags: android, ssl, basic-authentication

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers I have found are helping me.  I am trying to connect to a simple login service over SSL with Basic Http Auth.  The service is hosted at https://localhost:8443/login.  When I hit the service from a browser (on windows, OSX, and Android) it works fine, I put in my username and password and I am authenticated properly.  However, when I try to do this through code on my Xoom I get a ClientProtocolException that says "the server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response".  Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?  Here is my code

```
        String result = null;

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
        schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
        ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(preferences.getString(getString(R.string.Security_Login_URL),
        "https://localhost:80/login"));

        String credentials = Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
        if(credentials!=null){
        get.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+credentials);
        ResponseHandler responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            result = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two common problems could cause this:

1. You should not do the BASIC authentication yourself. The Apache HttpClient has all the functionalities already included to do the BASIC authentication. Look either [Basic Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java) or [Preemptive BASIC authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java)
2. Does your android device trusts the certificate from the server? When your browser trusts the cert, it doesn't mean that your device is also trusting it. Android has a very limited list of trusted certification authorities. You could check this from your device, when you visit the site on your Android built-in browser. If no warning message appears, everything should be OK. For further information about trusting additional certificates from an android device, you can look at my [blog article](http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/).

Enjoy